# (win10 python pip & conda crush) Jupyter notebook cannot run modules by conda, just after installing 'ipyleaflet' by pip

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, jupyter-notebook, conda

After installing ipyleaflet by pip, my win10 cannot run modules installed by conda before.
eg.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zvbL.png)
* have been using them, but now that message popped up

how to switch pip -> conda??